# Difference between service off and service stop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, redhat-enterprise-linux

Please can someone explain differences between **service stop** and **service off**:

for example:

```
# service httpd off
# chkconfig httpd off
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chkconfig` controls whether the service should start when your computer boots, while `service` lets you manage (start, stop, query status) the service.

So:

```
# service httpd stop
```

(notice that the option provided is `stop` and not `off`) stops the `httpd` service but won't prevent `httpd` from starting upon reboot, while

```
# chkconfig httpd off
```

disables `httpd` so that it won't start upon reboot, but won't stop a running instance of service `httpd`.

Answer (score 2):

The service command affects the currently running services. You can start and stop servers at any time as you see fit. But it does not effect the configuration that determines what are started at boot time. The other command changes that configuration. It controls what is started at boot time.

Answer (score 2):

**stop** stops the service if it is actually running right now.

**off** will prevent that the service will even be started at next system restart.

Often you use them together to mean: stop it now and don't restart it again next time.